# Input Id Name showing to URL?

Tags: php, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I have a problem, I am trying to make some forms in bootstrap however it messed up.

Once I converted the forms to bootstrap related they are no longer doing the job they're supposed to do.
What I am trying to do is to save form logs to a `txt file`, but they won't save.

When I add `name="test"` it won't work, instead it writes in the url.

**URL:** localhost/save.php?John

**save.php**

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("test.txt", "a+");
    $txt = "Name : ".$_POST['test451']." -> Surname: ".$_POST['loki'];
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

index

```
<form action="/save.php" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="loki" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Valid first name is required.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="test451" placeholder="" value="" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Valid last name is required.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the form (tags)?

Comment: I haven’t added them here but there’s form in top and bottom

Comment: How are we to know if the method matches or if there is one at all?

Comment: <form action="/save.php" class="needs-validation" novalidate>  and </form>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing the comment you left with this code: (edit: you added that in the question just now [in an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58505224/3))

```
<form action="/save.php" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
```

Forms default to a GET method if there is no POST implied. So you're getting the `?John` back because of it.

Add `method="post"` in your form.